# How to change the Text color of collapsing toolbar and the back button color of collapsing toolbar in android

Tags: android

Is there any library to achieve this effect below

- There is pager in the Toolbar
- This has to be a parallax effect of toolbar

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The CollapsingToolBar that is in the Android Design lib will do what you are asking.

You will need to apply a custom toolbar theme.  Here is an example (this IS your styles.xml file).

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomToolbarTheme" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <!-- HERE ARE THE CHANGES - Change color of different texts -->
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/wacky_blue</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/toolbar_color</item>
    </style>


</resources>
```

then you will need to set this on your App Bar:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        ...
        android:theme="@style/CustomToolbarTheme"
        ...>
```