# Android "app:titleTextColor" Doesn't Work in MaterialToolbar within CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:contentScrim="@color/purple_500"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/sam" />

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        app:title="Sam Chen"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/white"/>    //<- here, doesn't work

</com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Result:

[image]

And collapsed:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the Title Text Color of CollapsingToolbarLayout in both collapsed and expanded mode you can use the attributes **`app:expandedTitleTextAppearance`** and **`app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance`** like below:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:contentScrim="@color/purple_500"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
    app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/MyExpandedTitle"
    app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/MyCollapsedTitle">
```

where `@style/MyExpandedTitle` is your custom expandedTitleTextAppearance like below:

```
 <style name="MyExpandedTitle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.Design.CollapsingToolbar.Expanded">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/holo_red_dark</item>
 </style>
```

and `@style/MyCollapsedTitle` is your custom collapsedTitleTextAppearance like below:

```
 <style name="MyCollapsedTitle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/holo_red_dark</item>
 </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            ...
            app:collapsedTitleTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:expandedTitleTextColor="@android:color/white">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for my case, I just need the title and options menu icon to be white:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout

    ...

    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar">
```

For customizing color of title and options menu icon can read this: [How to change the Text color of collapsing toolbar and the back button color of collapsing toolbar in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53932999/how-to-change-the-text-color-of-collapsing-toolbar-and-the-back-button-color-of)